# Disable CSS animation on pseudo element inherited from parent

Tags: css, css-animations

The title pretty much says it all but here is an example.

Let's say I have a CSS 'loading spinner' as below:

```
.spinner {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    animation: rotate .6s infinite linear;
    border-left: 6px solid #222;
    border-right: 6px solid #222;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #222;;
    border-top: 6px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 100%; 
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

I want to add a pseudo element to this - for example with `content: 'loading...'` before or after `.spinner`.

Is it possible to ensure the pseudo element does not inherit the animation from `.spinner`, or must  a pseudo element *always* take what the parent has?

Comment: The pseudo is the child element and so when you rotate the parent, the child will automatically get rotated. The only solution I can think of is to apply reverse transform.

Comment: You could use the spinner as the psuedo element and text as main element. Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/uQ73y/1/

Comment: @Chris; I am not sure if you were planning to add your solution as an answer and so have made a mention of it in my answer and have also added a snippet. Please let me know if you wish you to add a separate answer and I'd have that part removed.

Comment: No worries @Harry, mine is more a suggestion than an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the pseudo-element is a child element of the parent it will continue to get rotated as long as parent has the animation. Even setting `animation: none` on the pseudo element will have no effect.

The only way to make it look as though the child has no animation is to reverse the effect like shown in  below snippet. What is being done is that the very same animation is added to the pseudo element but the `animation-direction` is set as `reverse`. This means that the pseudo get the exact reverse transform effect and thus would retain it in the same position.

```css
.spinner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  border-left: 6px solid #222;
  border-right: 6px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #222;
  border-top: 6px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Loading..';
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: rotation .6s infinite linear reverse; /* added this line */
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='spinner'></div>
```

---

The above snippet uses the default setting for `transform-origin` which is `50% 50%` but if the child pseudo-element has `padding` and/or `margin` then the `transform-origin` setting has to be adjusted accordingly to avoid the pseudo-element from producing a shivering like effect. The calculation logic is provided in the below snippet.

```css
.spinner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  border-left: 6px solid #222;
  border-right: 6px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #222;
  border-top: 6px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.spinner.parent-padded-margin {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Loading..';
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: rotation .6s infinite linear reverse;
  /* added this line */
}
.spinner.child-padded-margin:after {
  padding: 10px 8px;
  margin: 5px 4px;
  transform-origin: calc(50% - 12px) calc(50% - 15px);  /* calc(50% - ((padding-left + padding-right)/2 + margin-left)) calc(50% - ((padding-top + padding-bottom)/2 + margin-top)) */
}
.spinner.child-padded-margin-2:after {
  padding: 10px 6px 16px 14px;
  margin: 7px 12px 5px 10px;
  transform-origin: calc(50% - 20px) calc(50% - 20px);  /* calc(50% - ((padding-left + padding-right)/2 + margin-left)) calc(50% - ((padding-top + padding-bottom)/2 + margin-top)) */
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='spinner'></div>
<div class='spinner parent-padded-margin'></div>
<div class='spinner child-padded-margin'></div>
<div class='spinner child-padded-margin-2'></div>
```

Positioning the pseudo-element (using `top`,`left`,`bottom`,`right` ) also has affects the animation. It would also require the `transform-origin` to be modified accordinly in-order for the animation to work properly. A sample is available in the below snippet.

```css
.spinner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  border-left: 6px solid #222;
  border-right: 6px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #222;
  border-top: 6px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.spinner.parent-padded-margin {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Loading..';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: rotation .6s infinite linear reverse;  /* added this line */
}
.spinner.child-positioned{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
.spinner.child-positioned:after {
  top: 120%;
  left: 2%;
  transform-origin: calc(50% - 2%) calc(50% - 120%); /* basically need to subtract the distance from the left and top of the container */
}
.spinner.child-positioned-negative:after {
  bottom: -120%;
  right: -2%;
  transform-origin: calc(50% - 2%) calc(50% - 120%); /* basically need to subtract the distance from the left and top of the container */
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='spinner child-positioned'></div>
<div class='spinner child-positioned-negative'></div>
```

> **Note:** Both the above solutions work perfectly fine in latest versions of Chrome, Opera and Safari but are causing the text to have a slanted appearance in IE 11, Edge and Firefox. Firefox seems to require a separate animation which goes from rotate(-10deg) to rotate(-370deg) for FF while it gets more complex in IE.

---

The only alternate without setting the reverse animation on pseudo (child) element would be to make use of the **method mentioned by Chris** in his comment. That would mean setting borders and the animation directly to the pseudo element. This would mean that the parent's contents would remain unaffected as the parent won't get affected by a transform on the child.

```css
.spinner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  border-left: 6px solid #222;
  border-right: 6px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #222;
  border-top: 6px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='spinner'>Loading...</div>
```

Comment: While this solution does technically answer my question it is not an ideal solution as any deviation from the given position on the :after (including use of margins & padding) results in the pseudo element - in this case the text - moving in the direction of the spinner - albeit retaining the horizontal appearance.

Comment: @Rob Yes, it is not the ideal solution but there is no other solution (unless you wish to adopt Chris' suggestion). And, if you can show me the positioned text, I can help fitting it to work with this code.

Comment: @Harry, hello. Can you show how to make text inside (in center) circle? eg "OK" message

Comment: It didn't worked for me. However I just add the same animation as the parent but set the animation-time to 5ms and the animation is not visible at all

Answer (score 2):

For completeness to the question alongside the comprehensive answer from @Harry I produced a version with the text below the spinner. The method of this is to use the `.spinner` as a canvas, put the actual spinning circle `:before` and the `loading...` in the `:after` as follows:

```css
.spinner:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 24px auto 6px auto;
    animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
    border-left: 6px solid #222;
    border-right: 6px solid #222;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #222;;
    border-top: 6px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.spinner {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.spinner:after {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: 'loading...';
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='spinner'></div>
```

Comment: Looks good. For some reason, I just assumed that you wanted the text within the circle :D