# How to disable animation in a specific element in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do this animated circle [application](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-animated-circles) with a text inside it.

The thing is when I try to add the text inside it, it inherit the motion of the inner circle which I don't need. I want the text to be fixed without rotation. I tried to use `transform: none !important` and it didn't work with me.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="container">    

<div id="main">
  <div id="outer-circle">
    <div id="inner-circle">
      <div id="center-circle">
        <div id="content"><p>text</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content p{
padding-left:0;
 -o-transform: none !important;

-moz-transform: none !important;

-ms-transform: none !important;

-webkit-transform: none !important;

transform: none !important;

-webkit-animation: none !important;

-moz-animation: none !important;

-o-animation: none !important;

-ms-animation: none !important;

 animation: none !important;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610599/disable-css-animation-on-pseudo-element-inherited-from-parent/33610753#33610753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following in your html

```
<div id="container">    

<div id="main">
  <div id="outer-circle">
    <div id="inner-circle">
      <div id="center-circle">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div id="content"><p>text</p></div>
</div>
```

Add/change the following in your css

```
#main{
    position:relative;
}
#content{
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 59px;
    margin: auto;
}
```