# How to get the text to be fixed inside the animating div?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I have a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/hss3s3bn/6/).

I am unable add text inside the animating `div`.It is displaying outside the `div` if I add text inside the `div` as I am using `border-radius`.

I need the text to remain fixed while `div` animates.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div>Home</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background-color: #ADEAFF;
  padding:10%;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eff0f2;
  border-radius:50% 50% 50% 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 8px #aaa, inset 5px 3px 8px #fff;
  animation: square-to-circle 2s 1s infinite cubic-bezier(1,.015,.295,1.225) alternate;  
}
@keyframes square-to-circle {
  0%  {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  5%  {
    transform:rotate(10deg);
  }
  10%  {
    transform:rotate(20deg);
  }
  15%  { 
    transform:rotate(30deg);
  }
  20% {  
    transform:rotate(40deg);
  }
   25% {  
    transform:rotate(50deg);
  }
     30% {  
    transform:rotate(60deg);
  }
     35% {  
    transform:rotate(70deg);
  }
     40% {  
    transform:rotate(80deg);
  }
     45% {  
    transform:rotate(90deg);
  }
     50% {  
    transform:rotate(100deg);
  }
     55% {  
    transform:rotate(110deg);
  }
     60% {  
    transform:rotate(120deg);
  }
     65% {  
    transform:rotate(130deg);
  }
     70% {  
    transform:rotate(140deg);
  }
     75% {  
    transform:rotate(150deg);
  }
     80% {  
    transform:rotate(160deg);
  }
     85% {  
    transform:rotate(170deg);
  }
     90% {  
    transform:rotate(180deg);
  }
     95% {  
    transform:rotate(190deg);
  }
     100% {  
    transform:rotate(200deg);
  }

}
```

Comment: If text needs to remain fixed while `div` animates then you'd have to put it inside a separate element and apply the reverse rotation to the element with the text. You may want to have a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610599/disable-css-animation-on-pseudo-element-inherited-from-parent/33610753#33610753 (content and child elements will always be affected by transform on parent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are animating the entire `<div>` so no matter what you do, the text and all children inside that div will inherit that `transform`. You need to break it up.

You can separate the text and the dial into their own elements and put it in a container element and then apply the transform to only the dial. This way only the dial is moving and nothing else. If you set the container to have `position: relative` you can then `absolute` position elements within that container to your desire.

You can see it done here or if you prefer [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/augburto/j5sgapnw/1/).

```css
body{
  background-color: #ADEAFF;
  padding:10%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 90px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dial {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eff0f2;
  border-radius:50% 50% 50% 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 8px #aaa, inset 5px 3px 8px #fff;
  animation: square-to-circle 2s 1s infinite cubic-bezier(1,.015,.295,1.225) alternate;  
}

@keyframes square-to-circle {
  0%  {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  5%  {
    transform:rotate(10deg);
  }
  10%  {
    transform:rotate(20deg);
  }
  15%  { 
    transform:rotate(30deg);
  }
  20% {  
    transform:rotate(40deg);
  }
   25% {  
    transform:rotate(50deg);
  }
     30% {  
    transform:rotate(60deg);
  }
     35% {  
    transform:rotate(70deg);
  }
     40% {  
    transform:rotate(80deg);
  }
     45% {  
    transform:rotate(90deg);
  }
     50% {  
    transform:rotate(100deg);
  }
     55% {  
    transform:rotate(110deg);
  }
     60% {  
    transform:rotate(120deg);
  }
     65% {  
    transform:rotate(130deg);
  }
     70% {  
    transform:rotate(140deg);
  }
     75% {  
    transform:rotate(150deg);
  }
     80% {  
    transform:rotate(160deg);
  }
     85% {  
    transform:rotate(170deg);
  }
     90% {  
    transform:rotate(180deg);
  }
     95% {  
    transform:rotate(190deg);
  }
     100% {  
    transform:rotate(200deg);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
  <span class="text">Home</span>
  <div class="dial"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the text outside of moving `div` otherwise there is no simplest way to keep text fix

try https://jsfiddle.net/hss3s3bn/7/

If you wanted text should be inside animated div then you need to wrap your text inside `<p>` or `<span>` or `<div>` with any class and apply reverse animation on it

Comment: I want the Home to be displayed inside animating div with text should remain fixed

Comment: Then you need to wrap your text inside <p> or <span> and apply reverse animation on it